# About paging in group mode in ag-grid-angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

There are two modes of pagination under grouping, which can be switched by [paginateChildRows]="true".

1. Do not include sub-rows, only paginate based on grouped rows
2. Include subrows and paginate based on grouped rows and expanded subrows

But in terms of business requirements, group rows are only used for classification and display, which is invalid data. If you want to paginate only according to the number of all sub-rows, for example, if pageSize is 10 and pageNumer is 1, then 10 are sub-row data, excluding Grouping, but using ag-grid cannot meet the requirements. Does anyone have some solutions? Thank you so much

Try to first calculate the length of grouped row data, increase the number of grouped rows on pageSize, and then use the API to set pageSize to change the amount of data displayed.

```js
this.gridApi.paginationGoToPage(this.pageNumber - 1)

const groupNodesLength = currentTableNodeData.filter((node: RowNode): boolean => node.group).length;

this.gridApi.paginationSetPageSize(this.pageSize+groupNodesLength);
```

But the display is always inaccurate, and the value of this.pageSize will be changed when paginationSetPageSize